# Gcloud can't connect instance via SSH Port 22

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, instance, gcloud

nice day!

I was connected in my instance, but there was a warning that it was necessary to restart so that Ubuntu could be updated, after rebooting I can't connect, either via Putty or via Web Console.

I do not know what to do?

This error when try connect via gshell
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Firewall::
default-allow-ssh set 22tcp

Routes::
default-internet set 0.0.0.0/0 and Next-hop default-internet-gateway

I need help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot longer SSH but I still can connect with the cloud shell. When I run the recommended command for Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gce-compute-image-packages`

I get:

`E: Unable to locate package gce-compute-image-packages`

I guess this means that the Ubuntu repository does not have yet the required version (16.04) of `gce-compute-image-packages`. This implies that I will not be able to SSH until Ubuntu includes that package.